# Skrollr Restarts when Screen Width adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, skrollr

My Scroll animations work unless I am half of the way down on the page and adjust the screen width. Then the `skrollr` animations all restart as if the middle is now the top. I have to refresh the page at the top of the screen to fix it or the animations won't begin until I hit the last known "top".

Here is my Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<title>Template</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Services/Services.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/ParentHF.css">









 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll()
})
</script>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>








   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../js/enquire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/skrollr.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/_main.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">   
// disable skrollr if using handheld device
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera   Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    skrollr.init().destroy();
}//execute function
    </script>





      <script type="text/javascript">      
    $(window).load(function() {
$(".loader-wrap").fadeOut("slow");
 })
 </script>




    <script>
$(window).load(function(){

var s = skrollr.init(); 

});  //closes window load function
 </script>






</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Is your HTML generated server-side? I don't see any structure in the `<body>`

Comment: No, i removed the Html as i do have alot of scripts to look through

Comment: No i removed it as i have alot of scripts to look through i and i strongly feel its within them the the error lies. its so frustrating <:( i made such complex skrollr sites and its pitty that every time the screen size is adjusted the skroller animations restart. so in order to fix the issue i must scroll back to the top and refresh. A tempoary fix i found is to call for a Scroll top on refresh so when hitting the back button you dont end up where ever you left off with all the animations thinking your at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    var s = skrollr.refresh(); 

});  //close window resize
```

Comment: i added this to the bottom just before the closing body tag. it didn't work but thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

[`skrollr.refresh()`](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#user-content-refreshelements) is a viable solution, but if you have already initialised skrollr and assigned it to a variable (i.e. `var s = skrollr.init();`) then you need to call the refresh function on the variable instead, like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    s.refresh();
});
```

If you are dynamically adjusting element heights, you will need to manually trigger the window resize event. As an example, if you are using [jQuery's slide](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) functionality, you would need to trigger the resize once the animation is complete. Like this:

```
$('#my-element').slideDown({
    complete: function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
});
```

This would trigger the resize event, which will in turn trigger the skrollr refresh function.

Alternatively, you can also call the refresh function directly after the slideDown function, or whichever function you are using that is adjusting height on your page, like this:

```
$('#my-element').slideDown({
    complete: function() {
        s.refresh();
    }
});
```